# Execute a command repeatedly until a stop message is received

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to create a script that receive command from other script, and based on the command received it will execute a method with a while loop or stop it. I manage to make it works with the code below:

```
import rospy
import threading
from std_msgs.msg import String

class MonitoringInterrupt(Exception): pass

def cbCmd(nData):
    """Call back function when receive command from a topic"""
    cmd=nData.data
    print("Received cmd: ", cmd)
    global is_monitoring
    global t
    try:
        if cmd=='1': 
            is_monitoring = False
            raise MonitoringInterrupt
        elif cmd=='0':
            is_monitoring = True
            t = threading.Thread(target=do_something)
            t.start() 
        else:
            print("Unknown cmd")
    except MonitoringInterrupt:
        pass

def do_something():
    try:
        while is_monitoring:
             print(str(rospy.get_time()))
             rate.sleep()
    except MonitoringInterrupt:
        pass

def talker():
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():                
        rate.sleep()  

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    global is_monitoring
    is_monitoring = False
    global t
    rospy.init_node('Testing_command', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber('cmd', String, cbCmd)
    rate = rospy.Rate(20)
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

But it look a little bit messy. And I read in the forum that we shouldn't use exception to interrupt method. So is there any other cleaner way to do this? Some people recommend using `thread.Event` but I haven't success to implement that with is one. Also, when should I call `t.join()`? I want to call the method multiple times, and as I understand you can only start a thread once.

Comment: In Python, exceptions are actually used to control program flow and is not an anti-pattern as opposed to some other languages.

Comment: So, what about `t.join()`, should I call it somewhere or just leave it?